# How do I interpret $x \in [-2,3]^3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How should I interpret this notation or range?

$x \in [-2,3]^3$

does this mean $x_1 \in [-2,3]$, $x_2 \in [-2,3]$, and $x_3 \in [-2,3]$?

Comment: This means that $x$ is a point in the prism $[-2, 3] \times [-2, 3] \times [-2, 3].$

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.  $[a, b]^n$ is a common notation for the $n$-fold cartesian product $[a, b] \times \cdots \times [a, b] = \prod_{j=1}^n [a, b]$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I'd just call it a cube instead of a prism (though it's both, technically); most specific name over generic one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[-2,3]^3$ basically means $[-2,3]\times [-2,3]\times [-2,3]$.

So, $x\in [-2,3]^3$ means $x\in [-2,3]\times [-2,3]\times [-2,3]$ which means $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in [-2,3]\times [-2,3]\times [-2,3]$.

In other words, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ where $x_1\in [-2,3]$, $x_2\in [-2,3]$, $x_3\in [-2,3]$.